# What impact would have introducing the quantum switch effect in classical computing?

Tags: classical-computing

[This divulgation article](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/action/showDoPubSecure?doi=10.1063%2FPT.6.1.20180328a&format=full) by Prof. Brukner talks about the possibility of creating a situation where

> "A causing B" and "B causing A" which we call a **quantum switch**. Such a setup is similar to some predator–prey relationships, in which predator numbers influence prey numbers, yet prey numbers also influence predator numbers. Following [work](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2076) that Ognyan Oreshkov, Fabio Costa, and I published in 2012, we now know that the quantum switch is just one example of an indefinite causal structure, in which it is not defined whether event A is a cause or an effect of event B, or whether the two are independent.

[image]

The work link leads to a paper that explains with great detail how to achieve that, and it also includes some applications, like to [prove that two no-signalling channels that are not perfectly distinguishable in any ordinary quantum circuit can become perfectly distinguishable through the quantum superposition of circuits with different causal structures](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.040301)

I am a regular programmer without a background in quantum computing and don't quite understand the implications of such articles. What I get, and find very exciting is the possibility of having such expanded causality models as a tool. **My question is: how/where could quantum switch fit in the classical computing landscape?** Be it low-level hardware design or the (surely upcoming) `else-then-if` software pattern

Comment: isn't *"A causing B" and "B causing A"* an entanglement, in quantum computing?

Comment: By [the linked article](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2076) nope, entanglement would be a non-signaling correlation, and switch a signaling one (not sure about the implications, or how a "channel" is defined though).

Comment: @Adelin I [asked](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1517/1346) for that, in case you are interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what exactly you mean by "*fit*", but, generally speaking, there do not seem to be direct applications of indefinite causal structures for classical computing.

Indeed, the interest of techniques like the quantum switch$^\dagger$ (aside from the purely fundamental aspects) is that they provide methods to create non-classical correlations, and more generally encoding quantum information (e.g. qubits) into "causal" degrees of freedoms, as nicely shown in Figure 1 [here](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/advances/3/3/e1602589.full.pdf).

In other words, one could imagine a quantum computer in which the qubits are encoded into (a)causal structures.
However, apart from the notable impracticality of storing and maintaining many qubits encoded in such a way, it is also not known how one could apply operations between them.
Interestingly, in at least some limited form, this is possible, as recently demonstrated in [1712.06884](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06884), where two different such qubits were entangled, and the associated Bell violations observed.
It is not known if or how one could scale such experiments to more qubits.

---

$^\dagger$ It is worth mentioning that there have also been at least two (to my knowledge) experimental demonstrations of indefinite causal orders: [1608.01683](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01683) and [1712.06884](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06884).

Comment: By "fit" I meant mimicking classical behaviors (as you already described) with different implications, helping to simulate some stochastic systems more efficiently, or maybe even implementing no-delay predictive branching pipelines on CPUs... let's hope some of this is even possible.